# Wordpress api, getting users data

Tags: json, wordpress, api, mobile-application, appcelerator-titanium

I'm currently working on an application in titanium appcelerator, alloy - where I'm pulling data from wordpress via rest api. 
My problem now is that I need to get the data from the the users of the of the wordpress site. Info like name, email ect.
Anyone ever tried or know how it's done? The end tag: /users? Doesn't seems to be enough

Comment: [Have you checked this ?](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/)

Comment: Looks pretty useful ;) thx m8.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with official documentation on [WP-API docs](http://v2.wp-api.org) data that you need is not accessable through standart API requests and endpoints (it is only "visible" during editing).
But you can create your own route and using internal API/hooks to get all data and return it in json format in prefered way (see Adding Endpoints section on provided before site).